# DataFrames ratio between two variables using pivot table

Tags: python

```
class  PassengerId  Survived  

A             99705       136        
B             82056        87        
c            215625       119
```

How to calculate the ratio of people survived to total passengers in each class.

I want the output to be

```
class     PassengerId  Survived  ratio

A             99705       136      7333  
B             82056        87        943
c            215625       119        1811
```

Comment: `df['ratio'] = df.PassengerId.div(df.Survived)`

Comment: I much prefer the syntax `df['ratio'] = df['PassengerId'] / df['Survived']`, but either will get you there!

Comment: @busybear I tried both, and for all `%timeit` tests, consistently got approximately 2 ms better performance with `/` than `.div()` on test df with ~100000 rows

Comment: @G.Anderson I had a suspicion it was faster but wasn't sure. Good to know!